# How to clean up old publications on the distributor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

When I use the following script on the distributor, it shows me current and a few old publications that no longer exist. I've gone to the publication server and run EXEC sp_droppublication @publication, but it says the publications do not exist.

I've checked all the tables and the old publications are in a number of tables, MSsnapshot_agents, MSreplication_monitordata, and MSpublications.

What's the best way to clean this out of the distribution database?

```
USE distribution

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  PUBLISHER SCRIPT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmp_replicationPub_monitordata') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_replicationPub_monitordata;

CREATE TABLE #tmp_replicationPub_monitordata (
    publisher_db             sysname
  , publication              sysname
  , publication_id           INT
  , publication_type         INT
  , status                   INT        -- publication status defined as max(status) among all agents
  , warning                  INT        -- publication warning defined as max(isnull(warning,0)) among all agents
  , worst_latency            INT
  , best_latency             INT
  , average_latency          INT
  , last_distsync            DATETIME   -- last sync time
  , retention                INT        -- retention period                                               
  , latencythreshold         INT
  , expirationthreshold      INT
  , agentnotrunningthreshold INT
  , subscriptioncount        INT        -- # of subscription
  , runningdistagentcount    INT        -- # of running agents
  , snapshot_agentname       sysname NULL
  , logreader_agentname      sysname NULL
  , qreader_agentname        sysname NULL
  , worst_runspeedPerf       INT
  , best_runspeedPerf        INT
  , average_runspeedPerf     INT
  , retention_period_unit    TINYINT
  , publisher                sysname NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmp_replicationPub_monitordata
EXEC sp_replmonitorhelppublication;

SELECT      (CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 'Start - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN status = '2' THEN 'Succeed - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN status = '3' THEN 'InProgress - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN status = '4' THEN 'Idle - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN status = '5' THEN 'Retry - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN status = '6' THEN 'Fail - ' + CAST(status AS VARCHAR)ELSE CAST(status AS VARCHAR)END)  [Run Status]
          , publisher_db
          , publication
          , publication_id
          , (CASE WHEN publication_type = '0' THEN 'Transactional - ' + CAST(publication_type AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN publication_type = '1' THEN 'Snapshot - ' + CAST(publication_type AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN publication_type = '2' THEN 'Merge - ' + CAST(publication_type AS VARCHAR)ELSE '' END) AS [Publication Type]
          , (CASE WHEN warning = '1' THEN 'Expiration' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN warning = '2' THEN 'Latency' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN warning = '4' THEN 'Mergeexpiration' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN warning = '16' THEN 'Mergeslowrunduration' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN warning = '32' THEN 'Mergefastrunspeed' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)
                 WHEN warning = '64' THEN 'Mergeslowrunspeed' + CAST(warning AS VARCHAR)END)                 warning
          , worst_latency
          , best_latency
          , average_latency
          , CONVERT (VARCHAR(25), last_distsync) AS LastDistSyncTime
        --  , last_distsync
          , retention
          , latencythreshold
          , expirationthreshold
          , agentnotrunningthreshold
          , subscriptioncount
          , runningdistagentcount
          , snapshot_agentname
          , logreader_agentname
          , qreader_agentname
          , worst_runspeedPerf
          , best_runspeedPerf
          , average_runspeedPerf
          , retention_period_unit
          , publisher
FROM        #tmp_replicationPub_monitordata
ORDER BY    publication;
```

Comment: Have you tried recreating a publication with the same and then following the normal drop publication procedure?

Comment: @HandyD, Thanks for the idea!  When I create a publication using this script on the publisher, does this get sent to the distributor?  (Had to remove all at symbols).  I created it and dropped it and the old one is still showing at the distributor.

DECLARE publication AS sysname;
SET publication = N'pub name';  
EXEC sp_addpublication 
    publication = publication, 
    status = N'inactive',
    allow_push = N'false'